# Problema en controlador laravel 5.8 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mvc

Controlador

```
public function index()
    {
        $serie_eventos=Serie_eventos::all();
        $comisariosporE = array();
        foreach ($serie_eventos as $key => $value) {
            $ids = unserialize($value->comisarios);
            $temporal = [];
            foreach ($ids as $key2 => $value2) {
                $com = Comisarios::find($value2);
                $temporal[]= $com;
            }
            $comisariosporE[$value->id] = $temporal;
        }

        $equipamientoPorEvento = array();
        foreach ($serie_eventos as $key => $value) {
            $ids = unserialize($value->materiales);

            $temporal = [];
            foreach ($ids as $key2 => $value2) {
                $com = Equipamiento::find($value2);
                $temporal[]= $com;
            }
            $equipamientoPorEvento[$value->id] = $temporal;
        }
        return view('serie_eventos.index',compact('serie_eventos','comisariosporE','equipamientoPorEvento'));
    }
```

index view

```
<tr>
                  <th>Evento</th>
                  <th>Fecha</th>
                  <th>Duracion</th>
                  <th>Numero de participantes</th>
                  <th>Comisarios</th>
                  <th>Equipamiento</th>
                  <th>Opciones</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($serie_eventos as $key)
                <tr>
                  <!--'serie_evento','fecha','duracion','numero_participantes','numero_comisarios','id_equipamiento'];-->

                  <td>{{ $key->tipo }}</td>
                  <td>{{$key->fecha}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $key->horainicio }} - {{ $key->horafin }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $key->participantes }}</td>
                  <td>  
                  @foreach($comisariosporE[$key->id] as $comisario)
  {{ $comisario['nombre'] }}<br>
@endforeach
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  @foreach($equipamientoPorEvento[$key->id] as $eq)
  {{ $eq->nombre }}<br>
@endforeach  
                  </td>
                  <td>
```

Y el error que me arroja es **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

El error esta en el foreach del controlador, precisamente arriba de las lineas que dicen `foreach ($ids as $key2 => $value2){`

Al parecer hay que crear una condición arriba de esta linea de codigo, un `if` con un `is_array`, pero probe y no funciono.

No encuentro el error todavia, no se que mas puede ser.

PD: Adjunte las partes mas importantes del codigo porque introducirlo todo es demasiado extenso.

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código como texto y no como imagen, considera leer [ask]

Comment: Ya lo cambie por el codigo y quite las imagenes, amigo.

Comment: Prueba pasar a `$ids` por `dd()` o por `var_dump()` para saber que estructura de datos te esta devolviendo